# c# list iteration inventory FIFO quantity track and profit calculation

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I am trying to implement FIFO inventory system to calculate Profit/Loss.. and I am stuck at iterating through the list to get the first in value.

My sample data looks like below...

[image]

I have come up to the stage where I can prepare the data set using List with generic class object as below.

What I am trying to achieve is, whenever there is OUT transaction type, I need to LookUp first non zero FIFOQuantityTrack and take the quantity out from there and also calculate profit.

For example, on the highlighted date below, I need to update first 1950 FIFOQuantityTrackValue to 1925 <= 1950-25(sold on this event) and update Profit_Loss to 2980*25 - 25*2800(from the entry where quantity was took from)..  and so on... so when subtracting value from FIFOQuantityTrack, if it becomes 0 then I need to move on to next FIFOQuantity.

I am not good at explaining but hope this makes sense...

```
public class OutputObject
{

    private int productID;

    public int ProductID
    {
        get { return productID; }
        set { productID = value; }
    }
    private DateTime date;

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; }
    }
    private int transactionQuantity;

    public int TransactionQuantity
    {
        get { return transactionQuantity; }
        set { transactionQuantity = value; }
    }
    private string transactionType;

    public string TransactionType
    {
        get { return transactionType; }
        set { transactionType = value; }
    }
    private decimal unitPrice;

    public decimal UnitPrice
    {
        get { return unitPrice; }
        set { unitPrice = value; }
    }
    private int? fIFOQuantityTrack;

    public int? FIFOQuantityTrack
    {
        get { return fIFOQuantityTrack; }
        set { fIFOQuantityTrack = value; }
    }
    private int currentQuantity;

    public int CurrentQuantity
    {
        get { return currentQuantity; }
        set { currentQuantity = value; }
    }
    private decimal profitLoss;

    public decimal ProfitLoss
    {
        get { return profitLoss; }
        set { profitLoss = value; }
    }


}

#endregion
List<OutputObject> ListOutputObject;
```

Comment: I see a lot of unnecessary properties with backing fields that could be automatic properties.  What I don't see is what you've tried so far in terms of data access.  How are you accessing your data and what type of storage is your data in?

Comment: @DavidL It's coming from database but I am using integration tool to process FIFO logic. I have stored them in the list but this doesn't have to be a list. It could be other data structure...

Comment: by "First in" do you mean depending on datetime? or depending on order of list?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary First in is based on datetime.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple SUM of (UnitPrice * Quantity * IN/OUT) will get you the result.
For IN use -1 and for OUT just use 1.

Comment: No It won't work. Since Unit Price is different when we stock in.

Comment: You multiply the Quantity you stock in ... so you'll get the purchase price of that lot... so In case you have purchased a product at 80,90, 100 in lots of 1000, you'll get  80*1000 + 90*1000 + 100* 10000. Isn't that what you need ?